# CSS Table to read left to right

Tags: css

I do not have control over the markup on this table, only the CSS.

I'm looking to make the table read from left to right instead of the vertical.

http://jsbin.com/oXOYayA/1/edit

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `table read from left to right instead of the vertical`????

Comment: Can't you use inline-css?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is to read horizontally instead of vertically. So the coloured TD's would start the row.

Comment: @Adsy: why on earth would that matter?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsbin.com/oXOYayA/15/edit) works.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/VkUV2/)

```
body {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
table {
width: 100%;
border: none;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 100px;
-webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
}

tr {
display: table-row;
vertical-align: inherit;
border-color: inherit;
-webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
}

table tr:first-child td {
background: #e9e9e9;
}
table tr td {
padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #43447b;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
height:60px;
}
```

Just make sure you replace *body* with whatever container holds the table to be flipped.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to work in older browsers? For newer browsers I'd recommend rotating the table 90deg counter-clockwise using CSS3 transforms and then rotate the cells back the other way.

http://jsbin.com/oXOYayA/5/edit

Works best if all cells are square (that's why i set explict width/height on the TDs

EDIT: Actually, if you combine my answer with nkmols it can be done: http://jsbin.com/oXOYayA/7/edit

The trick is to combine the transforms

```
transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
```

It rotates part of the table out of view but you can fix that easily enough by setting a pivot point for the transform.

Comment: I was trying the same thing, but this reverses the order of the rows

Comment: it does but it's the only thing i can think of. I thinked you're boned, sorry. You might have been able to do something with the `writing-mode` property but I don't think a single browser supports it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. But you want the `<th>` on the bottom and `<td>` at the top?

You can mirror the table on the Y-axis and *reset the mirror* on the td so the text isn't mirrored:

```
table {
width: 100%;
border: none;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 28px;
-moz-transform: scaleY(-1); /* Gecko */
-o-transform: scaleY(-1); /* Operah */
-webkit-transform: scaleY(-1); /* webkit */
transform: scaleY(-1); /* standard */
}

table tr td {
padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #43447b;

-moz-transform: scaleY(-1); /* Gecko */
-o-transform: scaleY(-1); /* Operah */
-webkit-transform: scaleY(-1); /* webkit */
transform: scaleY(-1); /* standard */
}
```

### [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oXOYayA/10/edit)

Comment: really nice trick but I think he wants the head cells down the left side, not underneath.

Comment: Yeah, he wants something like a matrix transpose.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you can't change the markup but I have used < thead > < tbody > tags. In your case, just use class names to replace the thead and tbody tags.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/aCs7c/

For the table:

```
<table border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
            <th>Head 3</th>
            <th>Head 4</th>
            <th>Head 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>188</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>211</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
thead { 
    display: block; 
    float: left;
}
tbody {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
thead tr {
    display: block;
}
th {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
tbody tr {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
}
td {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
/*fix your borders*/
```

you can also refer to http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/